# React Native Link to gmail app works, but displays alert message: "Failed to open link. Unable to understand the link"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<CtaButton
    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('googlegmail://app')}
/>
```

This link actually works as intended, navigating to the gmail inbox, but you have to click out of an alert window that says: Failed to open link. Unable to understand the link.

I'm confused because it does seem to be understanding the link?

[The alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVU9r.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you only want to open Gmail? You could use a package like [this one](https://github.com/leanmotherfuckers/react-native-email-link) to open the user's default client, or peek into the library to see how they do it.

Comment: Yeah, we have a button for default and a button for gmail

Comment: Copy that. I can't find specs on linking to the Gmail app after a quick search, where did you get `googlegmail://app` from? Have you tried just `googlegmail://` or something?